# Avi html5 or jquery player?

Tags: jquery, html

I have been looking all over the web googling but i can't find a single video player player for html5 or jquery to play `.avi`s. I am open for any suggestions in how to solve this problem.

Comment: sorry i am new is that good or bad?

Answer (score 1):

the AVI format isn't an HTML format. You can use a free tool such as [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) to generate the formats you need to support all browsers. Then you just use a video tag...

```
<video autobuffer="" controls="">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/ogg" src="video.ogv"></source>
    <source type="video/webm" src="video.webm"></source>
</video>
```

Comment: I have allot of .avi files and growing how can i do this prosses automatically

Comment: You can run batches in the latest version.

Comment: @AsimPoptani You can select multiple files and convert them all with 1 click.  Just click and come back when it's done :)

Comment: @Archer ok i could do that however lets say person x uploaded a video how would i automatically start converting the video immediatly?

Comment: When video uploading is done, check for the extension and if avi pass this file as a parameter to the batch procedure to convert the file into different format, till then keeps user waiting sayinh process is converting your video